Why doesn’t the commandment to obliterate Amalek run afoul of children not dying for their father's sins?
How does the Torah's command to obliterate Amalek, due to their attack on the Israelites during the Exodus (Shemos 17:8-16, Devarim 25:17-19), align with the principle that "children shall not die for their fathers' sins" (Devarim 24:16)?
Is the distinction between the command to obliterate Amalek and the prohibition against punishing children for their fathers' sins rooted in the difference between national identity (Amalek as a collective entity) and individual accountability?
(By extension the question can be broadened to include the prohibition against an amoni or moavi marrying into Israel which is explained as due to ancestral malice)

Some said the commandment was never to kill Amalekites.  Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch pointed out that the commandment was to destroy “the remembrance of Amalek”, not to kill Amalekites. [Hirsch on Deut. 25] Likewise, the Sfat Emet said that the commandment was to hate Amalek, not perform any action against them. [Shemot Zakhor 346] The Chafetz Chaim added that God will eliminate Amalek. Jews are only commanded to remember what Amalek did to them.  Rabbi Simcha Bunim pointed out that the Torah says to “blot out the memory of Amalek” (כִּֽי־מָחֹ֤ה אֶמְחֶה֙ אֶת־זֵ֣כֶר עֲמָלֵ֔ק מִתַּ֖חַת הַשָּׁמָֽיִם׃) in the singular, not the plural. Not the Amalekites, but Amalek alone.
Finally, the Rambam said that it is forbidden to declare war on anybody without first attempting to settle things peacefully.  The main condition is acceptance of the Seven Noahide laws.  [Mishneh Torah, Kings and Wars 6:1] This rule includes Amalek. Rabbi Yosef Karo, author of the Shulḥan Arukh, confirms: “If they do this, they are no longer Amalekites, but Noahides.”
Others ruled that only a king or an organized community can perform the commandment, not an individual. [Rambam in Sefer Hamitzvot, Ramban on Exodus 17:16, Sefer HaYereim 435, Hagahot Maimoniyot (Hilchot Melachim 5:5)]
